# Web Design Advice - Questions to WebDesign Gurus/Mentors

Tags: jquery, html, css, web

I am a junior web designer who has fair amount of knowledge in photoshop, HTML, CSS.

I want to move to the next level of designing websites that work cross browser + look cool. Here's what I need some help on.

Can you experienced gurus out there recommend me good books/advice that will help me fine tune my designer skills and help me create COOL websites the 'right way'.

My ultimate aim is to be able to create cool templates using HTML, CSS, Photoshop and jQuery and then teach people how to create them for free.

Please feel free to give your 2 cents. Every cent counts!

Comment: This question is probably better suited for http://doctype.com/ which is geared towards designers.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Can any one recommend any popular books. I will check out doctype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making cool sites is good an all, but to get to the next level you first need to make sure you can build **usable** sites. Once you are able to keep things to the bare necessities and provide the user with an enjoyable experience, you'll be able to add bling and pizazz in appropriate doses.

**Some paths:**

- [Dont Make Me Think](http://www.sensible.com/buythebook.html)
- Learn more about [form design](http://www.rosenfeldmedia.com/books/webforms/)
- Participate in local groups like the [WSG](http://webstandardsgroup.org/)
- Learn about information architecture (read [the polar bear book](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596527341/) if you want to)
- Find out more about [accessibility](http://joeclark.org/book/sashay/serialization/)
- When you find yourself frustrated with a website take care to find out *why*
- Subscribe to some blogs like [Jakob Neilsen's Alertbox](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/), [Alistapart](http://www.alistapart.com/) and ... (there are a bazillion more out there, but I need to go to bed)

*Update*

On the other hand, I just was pointed to this presentation regarding form & function: [Eye Candy IS A Critical Business Requirement](http://www.slideshare.net/stephenpa/eye-candy-is-a-critical-business-requirement).

Comment: There are also some good tutorials at the jQuery site if you want to learn that, also keep familiar with the w3 validator to make sure you keep your markup clean and valid.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into using some CSS frameworks like:

- [960 Grid System](http://960.gs/)
- [Blueprint](http://blueprintcss.org/)
- [JQuery UI CSS](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Theming/API#The_jQuery_UI_CSS_Framework)